# Improve order by json field performance on mysql

Tags: mysql, json

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `session_id` mediumint(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `data` json NOT NULL,
  `jobname` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci GENERATED ALWAYS AS
    (json_unquote(json_extract(`data`,'$.jobname'))) VIRTUAL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
PARTITION BY HASH (session_id)
PARTITIONS 10;

ALTER TABLE `mytable`
  ADD KEY `session` (`session_id`),
  ADD KEY `jobname` (`jobname`);
```

It has 2 million rows.

When execute this query, it takes around 23 sec to get the result.

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(f.data, '$.jobdesc') AS jobdesc
FROM mytable f 
WHERE f.session_id = 1
ORDER BY jobdesc DESC
```

I understand that it is slow because there is no index for jobdesc field.
On data's column, I have 12 fields. I want to let user to be able to sort all fields. If I add index for each field, is it good approach? 
Is there any way to improve it?

I am using MYSQL 5.7.13.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create a virtual column with an index for each of your 12 fields, if you want the user to have the option of sorting by.

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `session_id` mediumint(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `data` json NOT NULL,
  `jobname` varchar(100) AS (json_unquote(json_extract(`data`,'$.jobname'))),
  `jobdesc` varchar(100) AS (json_unquote(json_extract(`data`,'$.jobdesc'))),
  ...other extracted virtual fields...
  KEY (`jobname`),
  KEY (`jobdesc`),
  ...other indexes on virtual columns...
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
PARTITION BY HASH (session_id)
PARTITIONS 10;
```

This makes me wonder: why bother using JSON? Why not just declare 12 conventional, non-virtual columns with indexes?

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `session_id` mediumint(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  ...no `data` column needed...
  `jobname` varchar(100),
  `jobdesc` varchar(100),
  ...
  KEY (`jobname`),
  KEY (`jobdesc`),
  ...
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
PARTITION BY HASH (session_id)
PARTITIONS 10;
```

JSON is best when you treat it as a single atomic document, and don't try to use SQL operations on fields within it. If you regularly need to access fields within your JSON, make them into conventional columns.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your suggestion. The reason I use json because I want to reduce the size of table and not every record has all the fields. I guess mysql json type is not as good as mongodb.

Comment: Are you aware that NULL doesn't take any space in MySQL? If you don't need every column on every row, just leave them NULL.